geolocation.watchPosition() fails with POSITION_UNAVAILABLE intermittently in iOS Safari
I am making this call to watchPosition:
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, {
  maximumAge: 10000,
  timeout: 10000,
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
});

About 90% of the time this does not work on my iPhone 15 Pro. But it does work some of the time. In the iOS device simulator and on my laptop/desktop this always works just fine.
The error I get has the code POSITION_UNAVAILABLE with the message: The operation couldn't be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.).
My site is using HTTPS.
